Optimizing Data Fetching and Prefetching with React Query for Sequential Navigation
Here’s a polished version of your question in English, suitable for Stack Overflow:
Title: Optimizing Data Fetching and Prefetching with React Query for Sequential Navigation
I am using React Query to fetch data from a Node.js server in a React application. The loading process for the current data (weld) is relatively long, so I implemented prefetchQuery to load the previous or next weld data in advance, as users are very likely to navigate sequentially between welds.
Here’s how I’ve set it up:
I fetch the current weld data using useQuery:
const { data: weldData, isLoading } = useWeldData(); // custom hook

After fetching the current weld, I prefetch the previous weld if hasPrevious is true:
useEffect(() => {
  if (weldData?.hasPrevious) {
    const previousWeldId = String(Number(weldId) - 1);
    queryClient.prefetchQuery({
      queryKey: ['weldId', previousWeldId],
      queryFn: () => fetchWeldData(previousWeldId),
      staleTime: 5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 minutes
    });
  }
}, [weldData, weldId, queryClient]);

My goal is to minimize the loading time for navigating between welds by preloading adjacent data.
Is my approach with prefetchQuery a good way to handle this use case? Are there better practices or optimizations for such scenarios, especially when users are expected to navigate sequentially?
Would it be more efficient to handle caching on the server side instead of using React Query’s caching mechanism? For example, should the API return the current, previous, and next welds in a single request to reduce client-side fetching and caching overhead? If so, what would be the trade-offs in terms of complexity and performance?
